# Geb-Spock using wrong Groovy version

Tags: grails, groovy, spock, geb

When I try to create a functional test using:

`grails create-functional-test acceptance.tests.Logout`

I'm getting this error, because Spock tries to use a wrong Groovy version:

> | Error Failed to compile GenerateAsyncController.groovy: startup failed:
> Could not instantiate global transform class org.spockframework.compiler.SpockTransform specified at jar:file:/Users/reinaldoluckman/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.spockframework/spock-core/2.0-M2-groovy-3.0/396867de1bbbe11e85e197c22f0e6de07643185a/spock-core-2.0-M2-groovy-3.0.jar!/META-INF/services/org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformation  because of exception org.spockframework.util.IncompatibleGroovyVersionException: The Spock compiler plugin cannot execute because Spock 2.0.0-M2-groovy-3.0 is not compatible with Groovy 2.5.6. For more information, see http://docs.spockframework.org
> Spock artifact: file:/Users/reinaldoluckman/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.spockframework/spock-core/2.0-M2-groovy-3.0/396867de1bbbe11e85e197c22f0e6de07643185a/spock-core-2.0-M2-groovy-3.0.jar
> Groovy artifact: file:/Users/reinaldoluckman/.sdkman/candidates/grails/4.0.4/lib/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy/jars/groovy-2.5.6.jar

But in my project only Groovy 3 is a library.

Here is my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
        classpath "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:3.2.5"
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:${gormVersion - '.RELEASE'}"
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:views-gradle:2.1.0.M1"
        classpath "gradle.plugin.com.energizedwork.webdriver-binaries:webdriver-binaries-gradle-plugin:$webdriverBinariesVersion"
    }
}

plugins {
    id "com.moowork.node" version "1.1.1"
    id "com.github.ben-manes.versions" version "0.33.0"
}

version "0.1"
group "test_project"

apply plugin:"eclipse"
apply plugin:"idea"
apply plugin:"war"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-web"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-gsp"
apply plugin:"org.grails.plugins.views-json"
apply plugin:"asset-pipeline"
apply plugin:"io.spring.dependency-management"
apply plugin:"com.energizedwork.webdriver-binaries"

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.grails:grails-bom:$grailsVersion"
    }
    applyMavenExclusions false
}

configurations {
    developmentOnly
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom developmentOnly
    }
}

dependencies {

    developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")

    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    implementation "org.grails:grails-dependencies"
    implementation "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
    implementation "org.grails:grails-core"
    implementation "org.grails:grails-datastore-rest-client:6.1.12.RELEASE"
    implementation "org.grails:grails-logging"
    implementation "org.grails.plugins:cache"
    implementation "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"
    implementation "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:${gormVersion - '.RELEASE'}"
    implementation "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache"
    console "org.grails:grails-console"
    profile "org.grails.profiles:web"
    runtime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-properties-migrator")
    runtime "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-grails:3.2.5"
    runtime "com.h2database:h2"

    testImplementation "org.grails:grails-gorm-testing-support:$testingVersion"
    testImplementation "org.grails:grails-web-testing-support:$testingVersion"
    testImplementation "org.grails.plugins:geb"
    testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:$seleniumVersion"
    testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:$seleniumVersion"
    testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-safari-driver:$seleniumSafariDriverVersion"
    testImplementation "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:$seleniumVersion"
    testImplementation "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-api:$seleniumVersion"
    testImplementation "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:$seleniumVersion"

    implementation "com.github.jsimone:webapp-runner:9.0.27.1"
    implementation "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:4.0.2"
    implementation "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-rest:3.0.1"
    implementation "org.grails.plugins:postgresql-extensions:5.3.0"
    implementation "org.grails.plugins:views-json:2.1.0.M1"
    implementation "org.grails.plugins:mail:3.0.0"
    implementation 'io.github.http-builder-ng:http-builder-ng-core:1.0.3'
    runtime "org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.11"

    // Para tirar os warnings do application.yml
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor"
}

webdriverBinaries {
    chromedriver "$chromeDriverVersion"
    geckodriver "$geckodriverVersion"
}

tasks.withType(Test) {
    systemProperty "geb.env", System.getProperty('geb.env')
    systemProperty "geb.build.reportsDir", reporting.file("geb/integrationTest")
    systemProperty "webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty('webdriver.chrome.driver')
    systemProperty "webdriver.gecko.driver", System.getProperty('webdriver.gecko.driver')
}

springBoot {
    mainClassName = 'test_project.Application'
}

bootRun {
    jvmArgs('-Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always')
    sourceResources sourceSets.main
}


assets {
    minifyJs = true
    minifyCss = true
    includes = ["fonts/*"]
}

processResources.dependsOn(['npmInstall', 'npm_run_bundle'])
assetCompile.dependsOn(['npmInstall', 'npm_run_bundle'])


task stage() {
    dependsOn clean, war
}

tasks.stage.doLast() {
    delete fileTree(dir: "build/distributions")
    delete fileTree(dir: "build/assetCompile")
    delete fileTree(dir: "build/distributions")
    delete fileTree(dir: "build/libs", exclude: "*.war")
}
war.mustRunAfter clean

task copyToLib(type: Copy) {
    into "$buildDir/server"
    from(configurations.compile) {
        include "webapp-runner*"
    }
}

stage.dependsOn(copyToLib)
```

Here is gradle.properties:

```
grailsVersion=4.1.0.M2
groovyVersion=3.0.6
gormVersion=7.1.0.M2
gradleWrapperVersion=6.6.1
testingVersion=2.2.0.M2
gebVersion=3.4
seleniumVersion=3.12.0
webdriverBinariesVersion=1.4
chromeDriverVersion=86.0.4240.22
geckodriverVersion=0.23.0
seleniumSafariDriverVersion=3.14.0
```

How can I make Spock (that is a transitive dependency from Geb) to use the Groovy 3 (that is already in my classpath)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your Gradle configuration I do not see any Groovy dependency. So if it is on your class path, then it probably is a transitive dependency of whatever other stuff you have in there, maybe Grails or Geb. _(Disclaimer: I use Spock + Geb + Maven, not Grails or Gradle.)_ Anyway, the error message `The Spock compiler plugin cannot execute because Spock 2.0.0-M2-groovy-3.0 is not compatible with Groovy 2.5.6` implies that Spock wants Groovy 3, but on your class path is Groovy 2.5.6. So you need to fix your build configuration, either upgrade Groovy or downgrade to `Spock 2.0.0-M2-groovy-2.5`.

Comment: BTW, `Spock 2.0.0-M3-groovy-x.y` would be more up to date the `M2`. I am sure, Gradle has something akin to Maven's `mvn dependency:tree` in order to analyse your dependency tree. Use it in order to find out what is wrong with your configuration and where Groovy 2.5.6 comes from.

Comment: Hi, @kriegaex! Thanks for your time. About your comments:

1) Already tried that, without success (grovvy-all:3.0.6 as dependency was an attempt).
2) Thanks for the information.
3) You got it. Issue #619 is the answer. You can write that if you want.

Thanks for you expertise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick check shows that the [current master of Geb](https://github.com/geb/geb/blob/master/geb.gradle#L45) still depends on spock-1.3-groovy-2.5, so I am not sure if you can use Geb with Spock 2.0. But it looks as if you cannot, see [Geb issue #619](https://github.com/geb/issues/issues/619). Consequently, you want to stick with Spock 1.3 and Groovy 2.5 for now.

Comment: `"you want to stick with Spock 1.3 and Groovy 2.5 for now"` - Grails 4.1 is built with Groovy 3 and expects Groovy 3 to be available.  I think if you pull 2.5 into your app that is likely to cause problems.

Comment: Like I said in a comment before: _Disclaimer: I use Spock + Geb + Maven, not Grails or Gradle._ I was explaining the OP's question why from a Geb perspective the Groovy version mismatch occurred and how to fix it for Geb. If Grails 4.1 needs Groovy 3 and Geb needs Groovy 2.5, either use an older Grails version compatible with Groovy 2.5 or do not use Geb until a version supporting Groovy 3 is out. But the Geb maintainers want to wait until Spock 2 which supports Groovy 3 is final. I am just describing reality, sorry.

Comment: AFAIK and according to [this list](https://gist.github.com/ishults/82a68897d85122562f65), Grails 4.0.4 is the latest stable release and still uses Groovy 2.5.6. If you want to go bleeding edge, incompatibilities like these can occur.

Comment: `"Grails 4.0.4 is the latest stable release and still uses Groovy 2.5.6"` - That is correct.  We will be shipping 4.1 in a few weeks.  Milestones available now.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I'm just updated to Grails 4.1.0.M2 and worked. Thanks.

Comment: @reinaldoluckman, what exactly worked? Using Geb with Spock 2.0 and Groovy 3? If so, would you mind answering your own question, describing exactly which versions you used? A link to an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)-style sample project would also be helpful. If it reliably works for you, I would not mind if you unaccepted my answer and accepted your own one instead, as long as it is comprehensive. 

Comment: @kriegaex I will do that, with a comprehensive answer.  

Answer (score 0):

With Grails 4.1.0.M2, `grails create-functional-test acceptance.tests.Logout` worked as a charm. But I did some extra steps (to avoid bleeding edge, as @kriegaex says in comments).

What I did was:

1. Updated to Grails 4.1.0.M2
2. Rolled back to Gradle 5.1.1 (recommended version)
3. Recreated gradle wrapper (`gradle wrapper --gradle-version 5.1.1`)
4. Continued with Groovy 3.0.6 (3.0.3 gave a dependency incompatibility)
5. Everything else came from Maven BOM associated with Grails 4.1.0.M2 (as saw in my `build.gradle` in my question )

But the gotcha is that Grails 4.1.0.M2 comes with Spock 2.0-M2-groovy-3.0, that solves the problem pointed out in [@kriegaex answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64438449/263690).

Also, thanks for @jeff-scott-brown for the tips in the comments.

Comment: So what about Geb? Does Geb run with Spock 2 and Groovy 3 in this constellation? If so, which Geb version are you using? what does your Gradle build config look like now?